# Is it possible to incorporate Flask with Pyramid?

Tags: python

I'm building a Pyramid application, but I would like to have a light-weight REST API built in to it. I've built such an API already with Flask, so is it possible to build my application in both Flask and Pyramid simultaneously?

Comment: Yes; they are both WSGI apps. Just configure a router container to hold them, and map URL prefixes to one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. It is however very inadvisable and tricky to do so. You can build a light-weight API fairly quickly using [Cornice](https://cornice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is Pyramids answer to RESTful frameworks. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes; they are both WSGI apps. Just configure a router container to hold them, and map URL prefixes to one or the other. How you do this depends on your WSGI server (some have native support).

Alternatively, have Flask host the Pyramid WSGI app; any Flask route that returns an object that is *not* a string or a Response object, will be treated as a WSGI app and have the correct data passed in.